# Can one calculate a general mean for questions that use different scale length?

Tags: mean, scales

I have two sets of questions:
1). 5 questions with answer options from 0 to 10 (very unsatisfied to very satisfied) and
2). 9 questions with answer options from 1 to 6 (same meaning)

The study was already performed so I am not in the situation to adjust the scale.
Now I am required to calculate the general mean for these 14 questions for different variables (which are around 6.8xx). Is this a correct way to assess the general mean? Could you please also give me the source upon which you make your argument?

Comment: I'm afraid that this may not be a very satisfactory reply  but I have faced this situation before and been unable to find a suitable reference. Hopefully you will have some luck here.  You cannot just take the overall mean from the variables as they have different scales and so the arithmetic mean will not make sense. The approach i used was to 'down-scale' the one with the larger range so that it matches the other one with the smaller range. You are losing data and some precision if you do this but it worked for me. Maybe 10,9, = 6,1,2 = 1 etc. (in a way that makes sense).

Comment: Thanks a lot Marina_ANOVA! Indeed, I wanted to do everything possible to avoid loosing some important data, but I guess it could be inevitable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, according to Colman, Norris and Preston (1997), who looked at different ways to transform different length scales, the best method would be the linear regression. See https://www2.le.ac.uk/departments/npb/people/amc/articles-pdfs/comprati.pdf
However for my case, I used simple linear transformation, which uses the formula Y = (B - A) * (x - a) / (b - a) + A. For further explanations see http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21482329

I hope it helps... at least it helped me. Good luck!